# Average $y$ from a range of $x$ in a parabola

Tags: calculus, quadratics, average

Given a parabolic/quadratic formula such as $ax^2 + bx + c =y$, how do I get the average value of $y$ given a range of $x$ ($x_{min}$ to $x_{max}$).

Real world example: if my formula represents the trajectory arc of a thrown object under the force of gravity, where $x$ is time and $y$ is height, I'm looking for the object's average height within a timespan.

Comment: Why the downvote? I've been searching for a solution to this and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average of a function $f(x)$ over interval $[x_1, x_2]$ is given by:

$$\overline{f(x)} = \frac{1}{x_2 - x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)dx$$

Applying that here, and assuming that you meant $y$ as a function of time ($x$ represents time, and we'll relabel it $t$ for clarity):

$$\overline{y(t)} = \frac{1}{t_2 - t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2} (at^2 + bt + c)dt = \frac{\frac 13a(t_2^3 - t_1^3) + \frac 12b(t_2^2 - t_1^2) + c(t_2 - t_1)}{t_2 - t_1} = \frac 13a(t_2^2 + t_2t_1 + t_1^2) + \frac 12b(t_2 + t_1) + c$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Now I'm not really fluent in the language of math... First could you please explain what _∫_ is. Then I'll need some time just to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Also, what is _d_?

Comment: That is an integral. In this case, since bounds are being applied, it's a definite integral.

Answer (score 3):

The average of a function $f(x)$ in the interval $a$ to $b$ is given as
$$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$$